# Get records based on conditions in other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are articles and comments. Comments belong to articles. The goal is to get all comments posted on articles that are published.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  # published
  def self.is_published
    where(published: true)
  end
```

.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article

  def method_name
    # get all comments where article.is_published
  end
end
```

Now to use that in controller:

```
@comments = Comment.method_name.order("created_at desc")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with scopes. Take advantage of [ActiveRecord#merge](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) to avoid duplicating the conditions of what it means for an Article to be published.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article

  def self.published_only
    joins(:article).
      merge(Article.is_published)
  end
end
```

Using it looks like

```
@comments = Comment.published_only.order(created_at: :desc)
```